# storing arrays into database

Tags: php, mysql

How do we store arrays in database?

What I am doing is the following:

// $data is an array

```
$v = base64_encode(json_encode($data));

$todo = 'INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES("' . $v . '")';
$sql = mysql_query($todo);
```

Also why do I have to call base64_encode before I store the array in the database?

Comment: Who said you had to use `base64_encode` to store it in the database? What's wrong with just doing a `json_encode`, or even `serialize`?

Comment: Generally is not good to store array into database. What are you looking after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is possibly wrong. There are many decisions you have made that are not by any means necessary, and they may also not be appropriate.

For one thing, storing "frozen" arrays in the database is usually a bad idea because you cannot do anything with them other than get them back (you cannot modify them or query based on their contents). Solutions that "fix" this issue are database-oriented and include changing your table schema. I don't know what you are trying to do so I won't go in more detail.

Then, if you do want to serialize arrays in your database (there are legitimate use cases) (**edit:** *and only intend to access them through PHP code -- as was very correctly pointed out!*), the only thing you *should* be using is the [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function -- not `json_encode` or anything else. This is the very reason that function exists. When you get the values back from the database, use `deserialize` to get the array back.

Finally, when injecting a variable into an SQL query, you need to escape it with `mysql_real_escape_string` (which you are not doing).

So it would be **much** better to do:

```
$sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO table (data) VALUES(\'%s\')',
               mysql_real_escape_string(serialize($data)));
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong, it's fine if you don't want to retrieve/search individual values in the array.

Comment: @yi_H: I do say "usually" and "there are legitimate use cases".

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with that.  Without knowing the purpose behind what he's doing, saying this way is much better may not be accurate.  Maybe what is really needed is a `split()` of the array, and storing data elements into rows.

Comment: why do you think serialize is superior? At least json doesn't tie you to a PHP backend.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: I believe the first paragraph covers exactly that.

Comment: @yi_H: That's totally correct, I was assuming that there is only going to be the PHP backend. Edited the question to point that out. Thank you.

Comment: Serializing as XML would usually be my first choice, but JSON is a little more lightweight.

Comment: @Jon, my issue was with your first paragraph, specifically "wrong on many levels"... it may be, and I don't disagree that there are some attractive alternatives, but it could be that it isn't wrong at all, just ugly and non-performant.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Fair enough. Edited; this should be an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You *don't have to* call base64_encode, but you have to escape the value with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call base64_encode().  json_encode() will already be a string... of course you are limited to UTF-8 encoded values in `$data`.

This is a legitimate way to store an array, although you could consider a table to be an array and store one value per row.  Additionally, you could store your data as an XML string, or even CSV/ TSV if your data contents didn't interefere with the delimiters.

Bottom line, it really depends on the situation you're in.  From the code you've presented, this will work, but if you want it to work well/ better, more information will definitely be needed.

*NOTE:* Sanitize your data before inputting into the database!

Answer (score 0):

Naturally you don't store arrays in a relational database.

Getting a base64 from your array seems to be a trick so that you can store a string in the database.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to store arrays in a database. Not many, but they do exist.

Comment: @George Cummins I didn't say that there a reasons against it. However databases usually don't directly support array field types.

Comment: Indeed, tables *are* arrays of data (rows), and that tends to get a bit "meta" when querying.  However, if the data is just to be stored and not queried against, it is a legitimate use case.